# rxjs 6 "skip" operator missing

Tags: angular6, rxjs6

I've upgraded to Angular/Rxjs 6 and I've noticed that the "skip" operator on Observable is no longer there.  I've not been able to find a suitable substitute, does anyone have any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.skip(1)
```

becomes:

```
.pipe(skip(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

> Make sure you have correct imports and then wrap your .skip with a .pipe( , , ,)

```
import { Observable, of, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { map, filter, scan, skip } from 'rxjs/operators';

  .pipe(
    filter(() => this.registrationForm.valid),
    map((registrationForm: any) => { // Form to-> ViewModel
      this.registrationVm.username = registrationForm.username;
      this.registrationVm.password = registrationForm.password;
      this.registrationVm.passwordConfirm = registrationForm.passwordConfirm;
    })
  )
  .subscribe();
```